# Is Apple G5 Mac powerful enough to do Iphone Game Development on?

Tags: iphone, macos, ios4

1.6ghz,
1.5GB RAM
FX5200 Geforce

I'm also assuming I can plug in any monitor I want?
Cheers!

Comment: If you do a search on google for: "ios sdk requirements", first hit gets you the requirements: http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because you need a Intel based Mac to do iPhone development on.

At least, with the stock developer kit - I see blog articles from a few years ago talking about how to patch the iPhone SDK to enable a PPC (aka: G5) build machine... but I don't know if those work with iOS 4.x SDKs.

And even if you did patch the SDK, XCode 4.0 only runs on Intel machines (at least according to Wikipedia)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I would image it is, but the iPhone SDK will only run on an Intel-based Mac. Specifically, the iPhone simulator and other iPhone specific tools are Intel-only applications. The actual APIs of the SDK should work fine on an older PPC Mac, but you won't be able to compile your code.